# Magento: Custom Javascript Alert After Product Add to Cart

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I've been following various tutorials to try and use Magento event observers to display a custom Javascript alert after a customer adds a product to their cart, but can't seem to get anything. Am I even close to going down the right track?

My Module:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Shoplio_XS>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Shoplio_XS>
    </modules>
</config>
```

My config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Shoplio_XS>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Shoplio_XS>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <sales_quote_product_add_after>
                <observers>
                    <Shoplio_XS_Model_Observer>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Shoplio_XS_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>Mytestmethod</method>
                    </Shoplio_XS_Model_Observer>
                </observers>
            </sales_quote_product_add_after>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

My observer.php:

```
<?php class Shoplio_XS_Model_Observer
{
    public function Mytestmethod($observer) {
        $event = $observer->getEvent();

        // Javascript Alert Here

    } 
}
```

I'm primarily following this tutorial: http://goo.gl/DRwd5

The only difference is, I don't want to display anything on the shopping cart page because I keep customers on the product page after a product is added to cart. I simply want to display a custom Javascript alert on the product page after the product is added to cart.

Comment: Should the alert popup on the product or on the cart page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to piggy back off the Magento core messages. I started by moving the Core Messages Block to my local folder and adding the following code around line 255:

/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Block/Messages.php

```
if(strstr($html, 'was added to your shopping cart')) {
    $html.= '<script type="text/javascript">setTimeout("myFunction()",1000);</script>';
}
```

The above snippet ensures that my custom Javascript function is executed with a delay ONLY when the core add to cart success message appears.

I added it right after:

```
$html.= ($this->_escapeMessageFlag) ? $this->htmlEscape($message->getText()) : $message->getText();
```

Then, in my view.phtml file, I added the following Javascript function to open a modal box with my custom message:

```
function xsModal() {
    Modalbox.show($('modal-id'), {title: 'My Custom Message', width: 600});
}
```

Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

You can NOT do Javascript with a  Magento Observer because observer code is 'executed' on the server-side, before sending the result back to your browser (while JS is done on the client-side within your browser)

What you can do is

in app/design/frontend/default/[theme]/template/catalog/product/view.phtml

```
 var productAddToCartForm = new VarienForm('product_addtocart_form');
 productAddToCartForm.submit = function(button, url) {
        if (this.validator.validate()) {

            alert('here');

            var form = this.form;
            var oldUrl = form.action;

            if (url) {
               form.action = url;
            }
            var e = null;
            try {
                this.form.submit();
            } catch (e) {
            }
            this.form.action = oldUrl;
            if (e) {
                throw e;
            }

            if (button && button != 'undefined') {
                button.disabled = true;
            }

        }

 }.bind(productAddToCartForm);
```

Comment: R.S., thanks for your response. This gets me close, however the alert comes before the product is actually added to the cart. I'm trying to display the alert after the product is successfully added and the product page reloads. The key is only displaying the alert after the product has been completely added to the cart.

Comment: Take a look @  http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/8558/ ... then you could create custom logic on what to do next (eg. create you own js forward to cart page logic)